# Implementing user roles in android applications

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have been researching on how to implement user roles in android applications but am not finding any examples. Am making an android classroom app with many users who can join many groups but I want to have super users who see certain controls like delete user, add user controls etc basically an admin/user/moderator depending on the role-type. 
How do you structure this on the android and database side? ASP has tools like identity that handle this out of the box for web apps are there any for android apps?

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question. Are you using web.api as your backend? How is the app build, and so on...

Comment: Yes there is a web api with a sqlserver on the backend... Am asking is how is it going to be implemented on the db side